# What is the difference between automating using http requests vs selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, httprequest

I am a bot developer in selenium webdriver Java and I'm using a browser HtmlunitDriver headless but it's complicated when I have to deal with javascript, so, which is better when I have to automate page? Sending HTTP get and post requests or continue using webdriver?

I'm confused because, for example, how can I click a button and wait for a page to load (example: when I open a page like Ad.fly) and I have to wait 5 seconds until the button is ready sending http request, this is what I am confused by, thanks a lot for your answers!!

Comment: I think there are two questions here.  The first compares two methods of writing bots (which may be a better question on Programmers.stackexchange.com but possibly doesn't belong at Stack Overflow, and perhaps a question on waiting to load a page before pressing a button (perhaps in selenium?).  I'd suggest asking the second part in a seperate question, and include any source code you've tried, and let us know what did not work.

Comment: thanks for repply i am not including code because i am developing anything i only wanna know how can i do click in a button or wait for a page to load using http request. sorry for my bad drafting.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the answer using a search engine?  I would think that information is available already.  If so, please at least give us what you searched on and what pages you found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use HTTP requests if you just want to make calls (i.e. to REST services).  Use selenium (or other web automation tools) if you need to simulate browser behaviour (i.e. run javascript in the page).
HTTP is generally preferable if you have the option - services are more stable than page structure (particularly if there's a published interface) and are more oftened designed to be machine-readable.  Web pages are designed for humans using web browsers, so they can change frequently, and adds a lot of overhead which doesn't make sense in a machine interface.

So, I'd suggest - look through the sequence of user actions you're trying to automate.  If you can express those as a simple sequence of HTTP requests, I'd do it that way.  If you need to run client-side javascript, or use other browser functionality, use selenium.

Comment: Thank you, it's always nice to be able to help.  If you consider your question answered, could you please click the "accept answer" button?